# How can I map the character ; in .exrc?

Tags: vim, macvim

As I code a lot I decided to make shortcuts so I can increase my speed a little bit. Besides, in some language we use a lot the character `;` so I decided to map it so whenever I press it,  a semicolon will be appended at the end of the line in insert mode especially.
I come up with this command:

```
map! ; ^[$a;
```

Then I realized that it cannot be made because of the second semicolon on the second part (infinite recursivity) ! 
I tried to escape it with the `\` but in vain !!

Answer (score 3):

General mappings tips:

- Use `noremap` variants unless you have a good reason not too (Like when using `<Plug>` mappings) to prevent recursive mapping.
- Specify the mode e.g. `n` for normal would be `nmap` or `nnoremap`
- Use key-notation (e.g. `<esc>`, `<c-l>`, ...) to improve readability. e.g. `<esc>` vs `^[`

Your new mapping for normal mode:

```
nnoremap ; A;<esc>
```

Note: Using `A` to append to the end of the line instead of `$a`.

The mapping in insert mode:

```
inoremap ; <c-o>A;<esc>
```

Note: using `<c-o>` to execute one normal mode command while in insert mode before returning to insert mode. Although you can do `<esc>A;` just as easily (It is shorter!).

Personally I think normal mode would the right mode for this. I also think you should think twice before over-shadowing the `;` command as it is pretty handy (See `:h ;`).

For more help see:

```
:h :map-modes
:h :noremap
:h key-notation
:h A
:h i_ctrl-o
:h ;
```

Comment: The command you have provided do not fill the task needed. I changed the command into `inoremap ; <esc>$a;` and everything is okay ! :D thanks !

Comment: I forgot to uppercase my `A`. Silly me. `A` is equivalent to `$a`. See `:h A`